# How to edit and re-run only the build stage that failed?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to get EF Migrations working on VSTS which is involving a lot of trial and error changing directory paths and command line arguments.  My build stages up to running the migrations are:

1. Use NuGet 4.3.0
2. NuGet Restore
3. Build solution
4. Test Assemblies
5. Publish symbols path
6. Run EF Migrations (a command line task)

It takes about 6 minutes to get to stage 6, only for it then to fail.  Is there any way to freeze the results of stages 1-5 and just edit and rerun the stage I'm editing?

(I've tried disabling Stages 1-5, but there are then of course no DLLs present for the migrations to run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using **private agent**, you can freeze the result of step1-5, and run step 6 (Run EF Migrations) directly.

  In Get sources step, you just need to set clean as false to achieve that:

  [image]
- If you are using **Hosted agent**, the build result can not freezed, it can only be used for current build.

  But you can add multiple Command Line tasks to re-run step 6. Detail settings as below (assume re-run EF Migrations 3 times if it’s failed):

  After the step 6 (Run EF Migrations), clone the Command Line task (Run EF Migrations) for twice:

  7. Run EF Migrations clone1 (Command Line task)
  8. Run EF Migrations clone2 (Command Line task)

  And then set step 7 and step 8 **Run this task** option as **Only when a previous tasks has failed**.

  [image]

  So EF Migrations command will run 3 times at most.